# Filtering recursively inside the same table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database with the following fields :

- ProductionBomNo
- LineNo
- Type
- Code

The `Type` column is an option column with 2 possible values (`Item`, `ProductionBom`) and the `Code` column has either the `Item` code or the code of another `ProductionBom` (so I can search inside the same table for `ProductionBomNo = ProductionBom` code)

This could happens more levels under the first one.

I want to create a view that shows the list of all `Item` that are inside all levels (explode the `Item` list basically)

```
+..............+........+................+.............+
|ProductionBOM | LineNo | Type           | Code        |
+..............+........+................+.............+
|A             |   1    | Item           | A1          |
|A             |   2    | Item           | A2          |
|A             |   3    | Item           | A3          |
|A             |   4    | Item           | B1          |
|A             |   5    | Item           | B2          |
|A             |   6    | ProductionBom  | B           |
+..............+........+................+.............+
```

Inside the same table there is also the productionBom Lines for the production BOM  referenced inside the previous table so:

```
+--------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
|ProductionBOM | LineNo | Type           | Code        |
+--------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
|B             |   1    | Item           | C1          |
|B             |   2    | Item           | C2          |
|B             |   3    | Item           | S3          |
|B             |   4    | Item           | S5          |
|B             |   5    | Item           | S7          |
+--------------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

The result I want is this:

```
+--------+-------------+
| LineNo | Code        |
+--------+-------------+
|   1    | A1          |
|   2    | A2          |
|   3    | A3          |
|   4    | B1          |
|   5    | B2          |
|   6    | C1          |
|   7    | C2          |
|   8    | S3          |
|   9    | S5          |
|  10    | S7          |
+--------+-------------+
```

Thanks

Comment: Post some example data and also the result you expected.

Comment: I need some help in formatting tables, lol, sorry I'm new :)

Comment: You should format your tables as code (click the button {} with your table selected).

Answer (score 0):

Try this(Assuming that the inside LineNo need to add ProductionBom's LineNo to get the new LineNo):

### Only for 2 level tree:

```
select coalesce(p.ProductionBomNo,t1.ProductionBomNo),coalesce(p.[LineNo],1)+t1.[LineNo] -1 ,t1.Code
from tableName t1
left join (select ProductionBomNo,code,[LineNo] from tableName where Type='ProductionBom') as p
on t1.ProductionBomNo=p.code
where t1.type = 'Item'
```

Tested in:<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e62cb/1)</kbd>

That's the result:

```
PRODUCTIONBOMNO LINENO  CODE
              A      1    A1
              A      2    A2
              A      3    A3
              A      4    B1
              A      5    B2
              A      6    C1
              A      7    C2
              A      8    S3
              A      9    S5
              A     10    S7
```

### For n level tree:

```
WITH BOM(ProductionBOMno,[LineNo],Type,Code)
AS
(
    SELECT ProductionBOMno
        ,CAST([LineNo] AS INT)
        ,[Type]
        ,Code 
    FROM tableName 
    WHERE ProductionBOMNo 
        -- Top level to start with
        NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code 
                FROM tableName)
    UNION ALL
    --Recursion link
    SELECT BOM.ProductionBOMno --get the ancestor BOMno
        ,BOM.[LineNo] + tbl.[LineNo] -1  AS [LineNo]
        ,tbl.[Type]
        ,tbl.Code

    FROM BOM
    JOIN tableName tbl ON BOM.Type='ProductionBom'
                  AND BOM.Code = tbl.ProductionBOMno
)
SELECT *
FROM BOM WHERE [Type]='Item'
ORDER BY ProductionBOMno,[LINENO]
```

Tested in:<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c768f/3)</kbd>

Comment: this does not work as expected, I can see only the list of components for the first level of my bom.

Comment: the problem is that the last 5 lines should have productionBomNo = A otherwise i'm not able to filter for the list!

Comment: Sorry my bad! Can you tell me how many levels you have in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following recursion query. Worked fine for the specified data.

```
;WITH BOM(ProductionBOM,[LineNo],Type,Code)
AS
(
    SELECT ProductionBOM
        ,CAST([LineNo] AS INT)
        ,[Type]
        ,Code 
    FROM ProductionBOM 
    WHERE ProductionBOM 
        -- Top level to start with
        NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code 
                FROM ProductionBOM)
    UNION ALL
    --Recursion link
    SELECT tbl.ProductionBOM
        ,BOM.[LineNo] + tbl.[LineNo] -1  AS [LineNo]
        ,tbl.[Type]
        ,tbl.Code

    FROM BOM
    JOIN ProductionBOM tbl ON BOM.Type='ProductionBom'
                  AND BOM.Code = tbl.ProductionBOM
)
SELECT BOM.Code,BOM.[LineNo]
FROM BOM WHERE [Type]='Item'
```

Comment: this seems to work, the only problem is that the ProductionBOMNo field should be the one of the first level for every lines (sublevels too)

Comment: Sorry, did not get the problem, can you show an example of the problem.

Comment: the final result shows a list where the first field (ProductionBomNo) is different between the lines of the first level and the lines of sublevels, it should be the same.

Comment: The query works as specified in the problem. Check this sqlfiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08d65/1/0

Comment: not exactly, I've made an example with a single ProductionBom, if I use your code inside a table with multiple productionBom this code is useless.